# Entity framework extract simple list from parent entity which has child entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two classes:

```
public class Profile
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public string ProfileDescription { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

with DbContext

```
public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

The profile is the parent and the matching collection of roles are the children
I have several similar classes.

I want to produce a select list with just the two required properties

```
ProfileID, ProfileDescription
```

in the query

```
SelectList(dbContext.Profiles.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList(), "ProfileID", "ProfileDescription");
```

that doesn't have the overhead of bringing back child roles

I have no idea how to do this in a general way (return the parent without the children)

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Comment: The query is returning not only the profiles but also the matching roles. For a large data set this is a significant overhead.

Comment: Since you marked the navigation property as `virtual`, Entity Framework will only fetch the related items when you access them. If you don't do that, Entity Framework won't, or at least shouldn't, access them. Note: adding an entity to the watch list in debug _will_ cause EF to fetch the related items.

Comment: Hi Henk - thanks for that. I thought that using the `ToList()` would force a fetch of everything?

Comment: It will only if you add `Include(profile => profile.Roles)` before materializing the query with `ToList()`. I will add these comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you marked the navigation property as `virtual`, Entity Framework will only fetch the related items when you access them. If you don't do that, Entity Framework won't, or at least shouldn't, access them. Note: adding an entity to the watch list in debug will cause EF to fetch the related items.

It will load related items if you add `Include(profile => profile.Roles)` before materializing the query with `ToList()`.

Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) on MSDN for more information about loading related items.

Answer (score 3):

you can get profile list with only two properties using

```
var profiles = dbContext.Profiles
      .Select(x => new {
             ProfileID = x.ProfileID,
             ProfileDescription = x.ProfileDescription
       }).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder).ToList();

SelectList profilelist = new SelectList(profiles, "ProfileID", "ProfileDescription");
```

Comment: Thanks for this too; this works perfectly. I am lucky to have two complete answers but sadly cannot accept both.

Comment: @PeterSmith thanks for your appreciation, if you like then vote my answer